# Trigger the invocations of system call in Linux, C program?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

When the below C program is run in a Linux,the execution of which line must trigger invocation of system call, why? What is invocation of system call ?

```
void main()
{
    double x=1;
    double y;
    double *z;

    z=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)); // line 1
    scanf("%f", &y);                    // line 2
    *z=sqrt(y);                         // line 3
    y=y*2.0;                            // line 4
    printf("y=%f, *z=%f\n", y, *z);     // line 5
    y=y/x;                              // line 6 
    printf("y=%f",y);                   // line 7
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A call to `malloc` invokes a system call because the operating system manages the memory.

Calls to `scanf` and `printf` invoke system calls because the operating system manages i/o operations.

Invocation of a system call is a call for an operating system service.

Comment: In most cases, malloc() only get as far as the sub-allocator that manages the C heap space.  The malloc() call MAY invoke a syscall to attempt to expand the heap space.

Comment: `malloc()` is not part of the C language.  it is part of `libc` library, which consists of system call wrappers and definitions.  So calling `malloc()` will always result in a system call

Comment: @user3629249 one of you should provide a link, I guess.

Comment: @MartinJames one of you should provide a link, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion above for people is syscall vs libc. Not every malloc will require a syscall - in fact, most shouldn't.

The Heap: LibC needs to manage the memory allocated to the heap(s). This is the area from which all of your individual malloc() allocations are sourced. When the heap is exhausted libc will invoke syscalls to kernel space to request more memory / reallocate / release pages / etc.

Malloc: LibC provides the user level code to assign memory blocks within the heap. It handles all the individual manner in which it allocates and frees this memory. If the allocation can't be done within the existing heap capacity it will trigger the Heap syscall.

If you look at the libc malloc code you'll see how this works between __libc_malloc() and _int_malloc(). In _int_malloc() it will fallback to sysmalloc() which will then perform a kernel memory heap change.